# Proper way to package a Laravel 5 Validator

Tags: php, validation, laravel-5

I wrote a bunch of validators that I would like to package so that I can re-use them in other projects.

Currently I'm registering them in `AppServiceProvider.php` but they also have a string declared in `resources/lang/en/validation.php` as well as other language files too.

What's the proper way to package the validator AND the language files so that consuming them from another project requires minimal setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a package, just create a new ServiceProvider in the package, in there you can register the validators and load the translation file(s).

Just create you package dir like:

- src

  - Validators

    - ValidatorX.php
    - ValidatorY.php
  - translations

    - en
    - x.php
    - y.php
  - CustomValidatorServiceProvider.php

---

```
<?php

namespace YourNamespace\PackageName;

class CustomValidatorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__ . '/translations', 'custom_validators');
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // register your validators here
    }
}
```

Then you can just add the provider to your config/app.php and use the namespace `custom_validators` for your package translations.

```
trans('custom_validators::x.test');
```

You can also publish the translations to your app:

```
$this->publishes([
    __DIR__ . '/translations' => resource_path('lang/vendor/custom_validators'),
])
```